# requireJS : Best way to add jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

**I am having trouble working out the best way to add a jquery plugin when using requireJS to structure my javascript.**

The plugins seem to be recognised before I optimize my scripts but then after optimization they don't seem to be found as part of the jquery object. My specifc case regard the jQuery easing pack.

I get the error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'easeOutBack'**

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this problem is related to the [problem posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171378/requirejs-problem-including-jquery-easing-pack-after-optimization).